# Textarea color values

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I'm building text editor, now i wanna change the color of user type for some specific words, like `<html>` and `<body>`.

CSS:

```
.html{
    color: rgba(0, 91, 255, 0.52);
}
.body{
    color: rgba(255, 1, 1, 0.59);
}
```

Javascript

```
function colorCode() {
    if (document.getElementById('textarea').value == '<html>') {
        document.getElementById('textarea').value == '<html>';
        document.getElementById('textarea').className = 'html';
    }
    if (document.getElementById('textarea').value == '<body>') {
        document.getElementById('textarea').value == '<body>';
        document.getElementById('textarea').className = 'body';
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<textarea class="lined" name="textarea" rows="10" cols="60" id="textarea" onkeyup="outPost(id); colorCode();"></textarea>
```

Now my problem is i can't make a multiple values at once, because when i writing `<html>` and then `<body>` inside textarea form, the color change but only once.
i guess it because the computer reading the values when i typing the first value ( `<html>` ) it work but while i typing the second the computer reading it as ( `<html><body>` ), is there another way to fix it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: So you saying i should use hidden display and add secretly divs? if you do can you help me with this?

Comment: That will mess up my whole code, i perfer not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They way you code reads, the classname will only change if the textarea content EXACTLY matches `<html>` or `<body>`.  It seems you might want a substring match if the text area just needs to contain those values to trigger a color change. So you might rewrite like this:

```
function colorCode() {
    var textArea = document.getElementById('textarea');

    if (textArea.value.search('<html>') > -1) {
        textArea.className = 'html';
    }
    if (textArea.value.search('<body>') > -1) {
        textArea.className = 'body';
    }
}
```

Note I also stored the test area node to `textArea` so that you don't have to search the DOM for that node every time you want to act on it like you were doing.

Comment: @Yotam How can you do what?

Comment: I got anouter problem, since the color change the whole text, you got me a solution for the code reading as i said, but i wanted it to be multiple colors, that both colors show for both values.

Comment: Notice: i forgot thank you for your help, and i will accept you answer if you help me itill the end :)

Comment: @Yotam so you only want the color of the individual <html> and <body> portions of the string to be appropriate color? With the rest of the text in the area being some default color?

Comment: Exactly! i want each tag diffrent color and normal text being default.

Comment: @Yotam that is not going to be possible using a regular textarea field, as inserting the spans that would be needed to add CSS stylings to the text would actually change your field value. You would need to look it implementing something like a more advanced WYSIWYG editor.  Which raises the question as to why you are just not using something already available, especially since implementing a WYSIWYG is something that is well beyond your current level of experience.

Comment: Then if it beyond my experience level then may i ask for a little help with a guide/ tutorials or simple source that may help me?

Comment: @Yotam My advice is to not bother re-inventing the wheel.  Google 'HTML WYSIWYG plugins' or similar for some already existing solutions.

Comment: I know, all i wanna do is recreate it in my way :) to get a little bit experienced. Can you please help me now?

Comment: @Yotam There is no help I can really provide specific help on how to create a WYSIWYG editor.  I can tell you that the approach you initially rejected of hiding your input field implementation and displaying data in non-input field will be essential in how you proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using a contains method for comparison, not comparing the value of the entire textareas contents.

Like this:

```
document.getElementById('textarea').contains('<html>')
```

You will also need to look for ending tags too then like:

```
document.getElementById('textarea').contains('</html>')
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains

Comment: Thank you, very helped , i try that but still can you give me a example that help for me code?